# How to write css for element containing specific text?

Tags: css, selenium, xpath

I've an element with text `List` which I want to use. I can write xpath like -

```
//li[text()='List']
```

but instead of using xpath, I want to use css. How should I write css for it? I tried with following by referring https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors but didn't work.

```
li:contains('List')
```

Comment: CSS cannot detect content. You would need Js/JQ for that.

Comment: @Paulie_D - It seems not that simple. the SauseLabs doc does suggest that Selenium supports a :contains() pseudo class. But I think that Selenium relies heavily on browser native functions querySelector/querySelectorAll, so the capability might be somewhat flaky and browser specific.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS feature `:contains('some text')` is deprecated, you should only use xpath in your case. There is no way to do that using CSS